# Cataclysm rom and Xposed

Tags: xposed-framework

First, apology if this question is already answered before, but I can't find this question after searching. 
For some reason I'd like to flash Xposed but afaik most of Cataclysm update is on delta update, is there any issue if I flash Xposed and then the delta update is released and apply it? 
I know I have to ask this on the rom or Xposed XDA thread, but I guess it would be convenience to ask it in here. 
Thanks in advance. ﻿

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what is being changed in the update. It may or may not affect xposed.

AFAIK Xposed works by integrating itself through patching of a framework library `app_process` (I am no xposed developer, so I may slightly deviate here from what actually happens).

To go in detail, every app and task is started as a "fork" (or copy in simpler words) of a base process called `zygote`. This is started by an `/init.rc` script through `app_process` inside `/system/bin`.

In other words, xposed creates an extended app_process of its own.

**Ok, but what does it mean?**

Simply said, unless the update provided replaces or patches out the app_process or similar to a very large extent, it will affect xposed; else it won't.

Now normally, updates have fixes to system apps and internal framework for bug fixes/new features. app_process is something which is generally not changed much by custom ROM builders and its code still highly resembles original google code (many times there isn't any change at all). So an update affecting xposed is likely rare (as its the system apps/components like `systemui` or `framework-res` that contain code for almost all extra features and are hence most common elements to get updates). Especially since its delta update, the chances of xposed being affected reduce even more.

Again, it is not a guarantee that xposed would not be affected, especially when it comes to individual modules' compatibility. As I said, it depends on what and how is being updated. Always have a backup first.